# Find SKNodes in a specified area

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I would like to be able to do something similar to the [`nodes(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483072-nodes) function in SpriteKit. However, for my use case, checking if there are SKNodes at one specific CGPoint is simply too specific.

What I would like to have, is an area, (that I can specify), similar to the `nodes(at:)` function, where I get back the array of nodes intersecting the **specific area**.

Is there some function that does this for me? Also, I would prefer **not** to bring any SpriteKit Physics into this.

Comment: Wouldn’t the way to find that out be to look at the documentation?

Comment: What makes you think I didn't check out the documentation beforehand? I've been working with different Apple's frameworks quite sometime now (& of course their corresponding documentations), but I noticed there are most certainly limitations to certain functionalities. That's why I asked here, hoping, maybe somebody knows a workaround or a custom method that could help me out.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is

```
func intersects(_ node: SKNode) -> Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether this node intersects the specified node. The two nodes are considered to intersect if their frames intersect. The children of both nodes are ignored in this test.

example...

```
//sprite created in Scene editor
if let locationBox = self.childNode(withName: "locationBox") as? SKSpriteNode {
    self.locationBox = locationBox
}
```

or

```
//sprite created programmatically 
let locationBox = SKSpriteNode(color: .red, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
locationBox.zPosition = 1
locationBox.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
addChild(locationBox)
```

checking for intersects

```
for child in children { 
    if locationBox.intersects(child) {
        print("child.name \(child.name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer, but sadly, this is not really what I'm looking for since I do not have any SKNode given that I could use to put in the `intersects(_ node: SKNode)` function (which is feasible enough for me to do it). However, I did find a solution for my problem, I will reply to myself later (in case anybody is interested in the solution.)